# how to get the clickevent of image view, but the imageview is in another layout working as header of the current layout

Tags: android

```
    package com.example.partialheaderlistviewscrollsync;

import java.util.Dictionary;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.LocalActivityManager;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

// here  i want to use the "img" click event to open camera.. the img is placed in another //layout called header....but the click event is not working..
//is their any way to have the click eevent of the element out side of the layout... i m //inflating that layout through infalter... but the click event is unavailable

```
    private ListView listView;
    private View header;
    private int headerHeight, baseScrollHeight, lowerHeaderHeight;
    private LinearLayout floatingBarHeader;
    private Dictionary<Integer, Integer> listViewItemHeights;
    private boolean setScrollHeight, offsetSet;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TabHost myTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(
                this, false);
        mLocalActivityManager.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState); // state will
                                                                    // be bundle
                                                                    // your
                                                                    // activity
                                                                    // state
                                                                    // which you
                                                                    // get in
                                                                    // onCreate
        myTabHost.setup(mLocalActivityManager);
        myTabHost.setup();

        TabSpec tab1 = myTabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab");
        TabSpec tab2 = myTabHost.newTabSpec("Second Tab");
        TabSpec tab3 = myTabHost.newTabSpec("Third tab");
        TabSpec tab4 = myTabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab");
        TabSpec tab5 = myTabHost.newTabSpec("Second Tab");

        tab1.setIndicator("    Details    ");
        tab1.setContent(new Intent(this, TabActivity.class));

        tab2.setIndicator("    Hours    ");
        tab2.setContent(new Intent(this, TabActivity.class));

        tab3.setIndicator("    Break    ");
        tab3.setContent(new Intent(this, TabActivity.class));

        tab4.setIndicator("    Details    ");
        tab4.setContent(new Intent(this, TabActivity.class));

        tab5.setIndicator("    Hours    ");
        tab5.setContent(new Intent(this, TabActivity.class));

        myTabHost.addTab(tab1);
        myTabHost.addTab(tab2);
        myTabHost.addTab(tab3);
        myTabHost.addTab(tab4);
        myTabHost.addTab(tab5);

        myTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

        View head = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);

        ImageView img = (ImageView) head.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Log.e("clicked", "hurryyyyy");
                String fileName = "photo-name.jpg";
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,
                        "Image capture by camera");
                Uri imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 4742);

            }
        });

        setScrollHeight = false;
        offsetSet = false;

        listViewItemHeights = new Hashtable<Integer, Integer>();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        header = header();

        listView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);

        String[] strings = { "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5",
                "item6", "item7", "item8", "item9", "item10", "item11",
                "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7", "item8", "item9", "item10",
                "item11", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7", "item8", "item9",
                "item10", "item11" };

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strings);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);

        floatingBarHeader = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.progBarFloat);

        setOffset();
        placeFloatingViewWhenReady();

        ViewTreeObserver vto = listView.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if (!setScrollHeight) {
                    baseScrollHeight = getScroll();
                    setScrollHeight = true;
                }

            }
        });

        listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                placeFloatingView();
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your onClick() function is placed in the main activity, the easiest way to generate it is to go to UI designer and select your imageview and fill in the onClick field, and put a name of the function, (example: onImgClick). then the IDE will generate event for u and guarantee that it will work!you just Copy the code from your

```
img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

to :

```
public void onImgClick(View view) {// auto-generated
```

---

here you can type your onClice fubction name :
[image]